# Button click is not firing in a multiview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls

I have one aspx page which contains 4 multiview controls and different views in each of them. In the first view which is the details view, I am entering some invoice details and checks the db for the datarow to appear along with the payment details.

The code works fine till it displays the datarow along with the payment control, but the payment control (user control) is not firing its validation controls properly (required field & regex controls). Besides the button click also not firing the validation code ,although it saves the data if I enter the correct details.

Could anyone of you please look into the below code and tell me whats wrong in it?.

```
    Protected Sub cmdPay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdPay.Click
        mvwDetails.Visible = False
        Try

            '  If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

            If Me.CreditCard1.CCNumber.Length < 14 Or Me.CreditCard1.CCNumber.Length > 16 Then
                Me.lblError.Text = "Please enter Valid Card details"

            Else
                Dim result As DateTime = Conversions.ToDate("1/1/1900")
                If Not DateTime.TryParse(Me.CreditCard1.CCExpireDate, result) Then
                    Me.lblError.Text = "Please enter the Valid Expiry Date"
                    Me.lblError.Visible = True
                    ' mvwMakePayment.Visible = True
                    ' mvwMakePayment.SetActiveView(vwMakePayment)
                ElseIf DateTime.Compare(result, DateTime.Today) < 0 Then
                    Me.lblError.Text = "Please enter the Valid Expiry Date"
                    Me.lblError.Visible = True
                    ' mvwMakePayment.Visible = True
                    ' mvwMakePayment.SetActiveView(vwMakePayment)
                ElseIf Me.CreditCard1.CVV Is Nothing Or Not Versioned.IsNumeric(DirectCast(Me.CreditCard1.CVV, Object)) Then
                    Me.lblError.Text = "Invalid credit card details."
                    Me.lblError.Visible = True
                    ' mvwMakePayment.Visible = True
                    ' mvwMakePayment.SetActiveView(vwMakePayment)
                ElseIf Strings.Len(Me.CreditCard1.CVV) > 4 Then
                    Me.lblError.Text = "Invalid cvv number."
                    Me.lblError.Visible = True
                    ' mvwMakePayment.Visible = True
                    ' mvwMakePayment.SetActiveView(vwMakePayment)
                Else
                    Dim OrderID As String
                    OrderID = grdMain.Items(0).Cells(1).Text
                    If Page.IsValid Then
                        Dim dtOrderPerson As DataTable = Me.DataAction.GetDataTable("SELECT o.ID,o.BillToID,o.ShipToName,o.BillToCompanyID,o.OrganizationID,o.InvoiceNumber,OrderDate,GrandTotal,Balance,CurrencySymbol,NumDigitsAfterDecimal FROM " & Convert.ToString(Me.Database) & "..vwOrders o INNER JOIN " & Convert.ToString(Me.Database) & "..vwCurrencyTypes ct ON o.CurrencyTypeID=ct.ID where  Balance > 0 AND o.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled' And o.ID=" & CLng(OrderID), IAptifyDataAction.DSLCacheSetting.BypassCache)
                        If dtOrderPerson.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                            Me.mvwMakePayment.SetActiveView(vwMakePayment)
                            Me.mvwMakePayment.Visible = True
                            'lblkaj.Text = "returned a record"
                            FirstName = dtOrderPerson.Rows(0).Item("ShipToName").Trim.ToString()
                            Dim entityObject As AptifyGenericEntityBase = Me.AptifyApplication.GetEntityObject("Payments", -1)
                            entityObject.SetValue("EmployeeID", DirectCast(1, Object)) 'No web user is returned as the data is based on orderid and companyid ,  Employee id of the web user is 1 hence using the same 
                            ' entityObject.SetValue("EmployeeID", DirectCast(grdMain.Items(0).Cells(0).ToString(), Object))
                            entityObject.SetValue("PersonID", DirectCast(dtOrderPerson.Rows(0).Item("BillToID").ToString, Object))
                            entityObject.SetValue("CompanyID", DirectCast(dtOrderPerson.Rows(0).Item("BillToCompanyID").ToString, Object)) 'Me.dtOrders.Rows(0).Item("BilllToCompanyID").ToString
                            entityObject.SetValue("PaymentDate", DirectCast(DateTime.Today, Object))
                            entityObject.SetValue("DepositDate", DirectCast(DateTime.Today, Object))
                            entityObject.SetValue("EffectiveDate", DirectCast(DateTime.Today, Object))
                            entityObject.SetValue("PaymentTypeID", DirectCast(Me.CreditCard1.PaymentTypeID, Object))
                            entityObject.SetValue("CCAccountNumber", DirectCast(Me.CreditCard1.CCNumber, Object))
                            entityObject.SetValue("CCExpireDate", DirectCast(Me.CreditCard1.CCExpireDate, Object))
                            entityObject.SetAddValue("_xCCSecurityNumber", DirectCast(Me.CreditCard1.CVV, Object))
                            entityObject.SetValue("PaymentLevelID", DirectCast(1, Object))
                            '  entityObject.SetValue("Comments", DirectCast("Created through the CGI e-Business Suite", Object))
                            entityObject.SetAddValue("_xConvertQuotesToRegularOrder", DirectCast("1", Object))
                            Dim genericEntityBase As AptifyGenericEntityBase = entityObject.SubTypes("PaymentLines").Add()
                            genericEntityBase.SetValue("Amount", DirectCast(dtOrderPerson.Rows(0).Item("Balance").ToString, Object))
                            genericEntityBase.SetValue("OrderID", DirectCast(dtOrderPerson.Rows(0).Item("ID").ToString, Object))
                            genericEntityBase.SetValue("Comments", DirectCast("Invoice paid from web", Object))
                            If entityObject.Save(True) Then
                                Dim dtPyments As DataTable = Me.DataAction.GetDataTable("select P.ID,P.PersonID,P.CompanyID,P.PaymentDate,Pl.OrderID,Pl.Amount from payment P inner join paymentdetail pl on P.id=Pl.paymentid where pl.orderid=" & CLng(OrderID))
                                ' Me.grdReceipt.DataSource = DirectCast(dtPyments, Object)
                                '  grdReceipt.DataBind()
                                '  grdReceipt.Visible = False
                                lblInvo.Text = OrderID


                                lblPyNo.Text = dtPyments.Rows(0).Item("ID").ToString()
                                lblAmount0.Text = dtPyments.Rows(0).Item("Amount").ToString()
                                Dim amnt As Double = lblAmount0.Text
                                amnt = FormatNumber(amnt, 2)
                                lblAmount0.Text = amnt

                                ' EmailID = txtEmail.Text.Trim.ToString
                                mvwMakePayment.Visible = False
                                mvwMessage.Visible = True
                                mvwMessage.SetActiveView(vwSuccessMessage)
                                Dim mailBody As New StringBuilder
                                mailBody.Append("Dear " & FirstName & ", ").AppendLine(Environment.NewLine)
                                mailBody.Append("Thank you, for your payment of invoice number " & lblInvo.Text & ". $ " & lblAmount0.Text & " " & "has been deducted from your nominated credit card. ").AppendLine(Environment.NewLine)
                                mailBody.Append("Your receipt number is " & lblPyNo.Text & ". Please keep this for your reference.").AppendLine(Environment.NewLine)
                                mailBody.Append("If you have any queries regarding this payment please contact our Accounts Receivable department on 04456666 and reference your invoice number.").AppendLine(Environment.NewLine)

                                ' mailBody.Append("Receipt Number :  " & lblPyNo0.Text)
                                sendEmail("Accounts Department", lblEmail.Text, "Payment Receipt’", mailBody.ToString)
                                ' lblEmail.Text = EmailID
                            Else
                                mvwMessage.Visible = True
                                mvwMessage.SetActiveView(vwFailedMessage)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            'End If
        Catch ex As ThreadAbortException
            ExceptionManager.Publish(ex)
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(DirectCast(ex, Exception))
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(ex)
            ExceptionManager.Publish(ex)
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the asp code

Answer (score 0):

check if you have proper validation group, also can happen if you are conditionally setting causes validation if so check that too.

Comment: Hi Vinay, I do not have validation group set on any of the validation controls?. Is that a normal practice? . Moreover I have conditional validation for checking the credit card details..